# Using CloudFormation, how do I associate a VPC to a Redshift Serverless workgroup?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-redshift-serverless

The `AWS::RedshiftServerless::Workgroup` Cloudformation spec does not have a VPC property, but it has subnets and security groups:

Example:

```
RedshiftServerlessNamespace:
  Type: AWS::RedshiftServerless::Namespace
  Properties:
    DbName: <redacted>
    NamespaceName: <redacted>
    IamRoles:
      - <redacted>

RedshiftServerlessWorkgroup:
  Type: AWS::RedshiftServerless::Workgroup
  Properties:
    BaseCapacity: 8
    NamespaceName: <redacted>
    WorkgroupName: <redacted>
    SubnetIds:
      - <redacted>
  DependsOn: RedshiftServerlessNamespace
```

When I add subnets from the VPC I want I receive the following error message:

> Updating the workgroup with subnet IDs [...] from a different VPC subnet is not currently supported

How do I associate the VPC I want - using CloudFormation?

Comment: Please provide complete code allowing for reproduction of your issue.

Comment: @Marcin I have updated with the "actual code." If that helps. I originally opted to show the AWS docs because it does not show VPC as an option, and the redacted code i believe is less helpful, but if you see something, let me know. How do you attach a VPC to a serverless redshift cluster in cloudformation seems like a pretty straight forward question

Comment: It's been 6 months and there's still no clear answer.  I have the same question: how do I provision a Redshift Serverless workgroup in a specific non-default VPC using CDK and/or CloudFormation?

Comment: I just tested now, with a non-default VPC's subnet IDs, and CloudFormation created the Redshift Serverless Workgroup in the correct VPC.  Maybe there was an issue 6 months ago, but it appears to work now.